# How do I repel bugs from face

Tags: pest-control

I have been doing some weeding recently, because it's summer now, and I really hate it when I sit down to dig something up and every flying insect seems to try to fly into my face. Is there some kind of natural bug repellent that I could apply to my face, or is there some kind of easy face mask or something like that that I could make?

Answer (score 2):

Look for a ***Bug-net mesh hat*** or ***head-covering***.

Most come attached to a broad stiff-rimmed hat. A hoop holds the mesh away from your skin to keep stinging insects from piercing you through the mesh.

A few are unstructured and can slip on over your bare head, a cap, or bonnet.

They are available with different mesh sizes from extremely fine (that are hard to see through in sunlight) to coarse (that let you see great but don't stop the no-see-ums that get into your eyes when your hands are dirty or carrying nitroglycerine over gravel.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen hats that were modified by hanging a row of wine bottle corks from string attached to the brim of the hat.  The corks hang down a few inches and are always jiggling around in front of your face, shooing away the bugs.  If you do this, make sure the strings are all about the same length and spaced apart to avoid the corks wrapping around each other.  Here's a pic.

[image]

Source bugoff.com

Answer (score 1):

You're baiting them.

Stop wearing perfume or cologne that will attract insects to you. The little creatures are drawn to your scent. The innocent lotions, oils, salves, unguents, and detergents you use on yourself and your clothing are luring the little guys to what to them looks like a big beautiful flower.

The most natural bug repellent is NO attractive odour.

Answer (score 0):

When my Uncle is riding horses, he says someone told him to tuck a dryer sheet into his shirt pocket or collar. He tried it and said it worked so well, he tucked one in his horses bridle as well. It's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Look for clothing impregnated with ***"Permetherin"*** which is a derivative of the chrysanthemum developed for the US military to repel insects.

The label lists effectiveness with many different types of crawling and flying critters you'd find in your garden. It is an insecticide (insects) and aracnicide (spiders). It is available as a cream to apply to the skin; but, there are possible reactions as with stuff like this. Read the contraindications and side effect warnings.

The clothing is good for about 70 washes according to the label if it is not dry-cleaned. Wash in mild soap only.

For exposed skin, the clothing label suggests using insect repellant suitable for direct application to the skin! (Go figure.)

Answer (score 0):

Natural repellent , flexible recipe, works really well:

- 100 gram of whole cloves
- 100 ml of mineral oil, baby oil, sesame, almond, etc.
- 1/5L of vodka (or any other alcohol/spirit with no strong nor sweet smell)

Put cloves in alcohol, stir 3 times a day, during 4 days. Then add the oil, mix well, and it's ready to use.

Spread a few drops in your face, arms and legs.

Comment: Is there a reason this recipe uses whole cloves instead of clove oil?

Comment: @Underverse Never tried but might work.